# Reverse Contents in Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reverse

I have an array of numbers that I am trying to reverse. I believe the function in my code is correct, but I cannot get the proper output.

The output reads: 10 9 8 7 6.
Why can't I get the other half of the numbers? When I remove the "/2" from count, the output reads: 10 9 8 7 6 6 7 8 9 10

```
void reverse(int [], int);

int main ()
{
   const int SIZE = 10;
   int arr [SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

   reverse(arr, SIZE);
   return 0;
}
void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
   {
      arr[i] = temp;
      temp = arr[count-i-1];
      arr[count-i-1] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;

      cout << temp << " ";
   }
}
```

Comment: Your loop only runs for half the length of the array when you divide the count by 2, so it only prints half of the array contents to the screen.

Comment: Look at your swapping with temps ;)

Comment: Using `std::swap()` would be foolproof - which is why it exists ;)

Answer (score 24):

This would be my approach:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 10;
  int arr [SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
  ...
}
```

Comment: I believe that the other answer(using `temp` variable) has a time complexity of O(n) and space complexity of O(1). What would be the complexity in this case?

Comment: @skr_robo The same. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) for time complexity. The implementation just swaps pairs of values.

Answer (score 16):

The line

```
arr[i] = temp;
```

is wrong.  (On the first iteration of your loop it sets `arr[i]` to an undefined value; further iterations set it to an incorrect value.) If you remove this line, your array should be reversed correctly.

After that, you should move the code which prints the reversed array into a new loop which iterates over the whole list.  Your current code only prints the first `count/2` elements.

```
int temp, i;
for (i = 0; i < count/2; ++i) {
    temp = arr[count-i-1];
    arr[count-i-1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `reverse()` function from the `<algorithm>` library.

Run it online: [repl.it/@abranhe/Reverse-Array](https://repl.it/@abranhe/Reverse-Array)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int arr [10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  reverse(begin(arr), end(arr));

  for(auto item:arr)
  {
    cout << item << " ";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Hope you like this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers look correct to me.

1. The first `arr[i] = temp;` should be removed
2. You should do a second loop to print **all** elements, not just half the array. The loop that does the reverse doesn't need to print it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing the array, you are printing the value of `temp` - which is only half the array...

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(int [], int);
void printarray(int [], int );
int main ()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr [SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    cout<<"Before reverse\n";
    printarray(arr, SIZE);
    reverse(arr, SIZE);
    cout<<"After reverse\n";
    printarray(arr, SIZE);

    return 0;
}

void printarray(int arr[], int count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        cout<<arr[i]<<' ';

    cout<<'\n';
}

void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
   {
      temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[count-i-1];
      arr[count-i-1] = temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this question is very easy: Vectors

```
std::vector<int> vector;
for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
{
    vector.push_back(i);
}
std::reverse(vector.begin(), vector.end());
```

Voila! You are done! =)

Solution details:

This is the most efficent solution: Swap can't swap 3 values but reverse definitely can. 
Remember to include algorithm. 
This is so simple that the compiled code is definitely not needed.

I think this solves the OP's problem

If you think there are any errors and problems with this solution please comment below

Comment: Kind of inefficient when you can just swap in place in an array.

Comment: You could do swap too but it wouldn't be anymore efficient than reverse because in this case they both do the same thing. But if you had to reverse 3 elements this method would be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question: Your swapping is wrong

```
void reverse(int arr[], int count){
   int temp;
   for(int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i){
      arr[i] = temp; // <== Wrong, Should be deleted
      temp = arr[count-i-1];
      arr[count-i-1] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

assigning `arr[i] = temp` causes error when it first enters the loop as temp initially contains garbage data and will ruin your array, remove it and the code should work well.

As an advice, use built-in functions whenever possible:

- In the swapping you could just use [swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) like 
  `std::swap(arr[i], arr[count-i-1])`
- For the reverse as a whole
  just use [reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) like `std::reverse(arr, arr+count)`

I am using C++14 and reverse works with arrays without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all what value do you have in this pice of code? `int temp;`? You can't tell because in every single compilation it will have different value - you should initialize your value to not have trash value from memory. Next question is: why you assign this temp value to your array?
If you want to stick with your solution I would change reverse function like this:

```
void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
    {
        temp = arr[count - i - 1];
        arr[count - i - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Now it will works but you have other options to handle this problem.

Solution using pointers:

```
void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
    int* head = arr;
    int* tail = arr + count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
    {
        if (head < tail)
        {
            int tmp = *tail;
            *tail = *head;
            *head = tmp;

            head++; tail--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

And ofc like Carlos Abraham says use build in function in `algorithm` library

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n, i;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[n - 1 - i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << b[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Procedure :

 1.Take an array.

 2.Then by default function reverse(array_name, array_name + size) .
  reverse(array_name, array_name + size) function exits in algorithm.h header file.

 3.Now print the array. 

 N.B  Here we use new and delete for dynamic memory allocation.
```

---

C++ implementation :

---

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;

   int *arr = new int[n];


   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  cin>>arr[i];

   reverse(arr, arr+n);

   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";

   delete[] arr;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you assign temp to array elemets and you should remove `arr[i] = temp;` statment. Next problem is that you are printing temp variable which shows only half of array elements(in your for loop). If you don't want to use STL vectors I would suggest this solution:

```
#include <iostream>

void reverseArray(int userArray[], int size);

void printArray(int userArray[], int size);

int main(int arg, char**argv) {

    int arr[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int sizeOfArray = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    reverseArray(arr, sizeOfArray);
    printArray(arr, sizeOfArray);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void reverseArray(int userArray[], int size) {

    int* ptrHead = userArray;
    int* ptrTail = userArray + (size-1);

    while (ptrTail > ptrHead) {
        int temp = *ptrHead;
        *ptrHead = *ptrTail;
        *ptrTail = temp;

        ptrHead++;
        ptrTail--;
    }
}

void printArray(int userArray[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << userArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will run only for `count/2` times. So it will not print the whole array.

Also, `temp=ar[i]` should be used instead of `ar[i]=temp` as value of `ar[i]` is not getting stored anywhere in the latter statement, hence it is getting destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<((s3)/2);i++)
{         
    z=s2[i];
    s2[i]=s2[(s3-1)-i];
    s2[(s3-1)-i]=z;
}
```

Comment: s3 will be the length of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to using pointers to solve this problem:

```
#include <iostream>

void displayArray(int table[], int size);

void rev(int table[], int size);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    rev(a, 10);
    displayArray(a, 10);

    return 0;
}

void displayArray(int table[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << table[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void rev(int table[], int size) {

    int *start = table;
    int *end = table + (size - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (start < end) {
            int temp = *end;
            *end = *start;
            *start = temp;
        }

        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach is swapping the first and last element of the array

```
int i,j;
for ( i = 0,j = size - 1 ; i < j ; i++,j--)
{  
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following example to reverse the contents in an array:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n, x;

    // order value for var x
    cin >> x;  

    // create array and the value for array is value var x
    int arr[x];

    // loop for insert values for array by reverse  
    for(int i=x; i > 0; i--) {

        // var i is number of elements in array 
        cin >> n;
        arr[i - 1] = n;
    }

    // show element in array
    for(int l = 0; l < x; l++) {
        cout<<arr[l]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: There are no variable length arrays in C++!

Answer (score -4):

try this can you better fell comparing to another codes.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[5]={4,6,3,5,9};
    for(int i=4;i>=0;i--) {
        cout<<"\n"<<a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't reversing the *contents* of the array as OP wanted, this is printing the array in reverse.