# C++ storing a string in reverse order

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I store the contents of an array in reverse order into a new array.

```
char str[13];
char revstr[13];

cout << "Enter string: ";
cin.getline(str,13);
```

How would I write a statement to store the contents of char str[13] in reverse order into revstr[13]

Comment: However, string is basically array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712903/c-reverse-contents-in-array

Comment: Your reputation tells you're not new here, still to remind you, the rule here is to show some efforts and then ask for help if **really** lost

Answer (score 3):

Look at this string:

```
char str[8] = "Jessica";
```

in memory it takes 8 bytes: 7 characters + terminating character `'\0'`:

```
J | e | s | s | i | c | a | \0
```

What you want to get is:

```
a | c | i | s | s | e | J | \0
```

`J` goes from position `0` to `7` (`length - 1`), `e` goes from `1` to `6`... till `a` that goes from `7` to `0`

You should be able to write that loop on your own now. Just note that these are fundamental basics that you should learn from some book rather than asking about it here.

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't show how to do it, but gives the knowledge needed to do it. Deleting mine.

Comment: Thanks and yes this is something I learned over a year ago so didn't remember exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::string`:

```
std::string newString( std::rbegin(oldString), std::rend(oldString) );
```

Comment: I don't think she is allowed to do that one.

Comment: This is clearly an assignment. The author is dealing with char arrays, not strings. What makes you think using `std::string` would be acceptable for that assignment?

Comment: @LihO, this answers the OP's question easily. If something is, or is not allowed, isn't specified, as this is not tagged as homework.

Comment: It assumes `oldString` is `std::string`, while OP needs a `char` array

Comment: @crush so I'm suppose to exclude the best solution because of assumptions about unspecified restrictions?

Comment: @P0W, `std::rbegin()`, `std::rend()`

Comment: @Yossarian yes and where is that present over here ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Is it really the best solution when the expected output is also a char array, not an `std::string`?

Comment: @crush the implication is "don't use char arrays". It's not the first time some asks "how to allocate an array of 10 ints" and the best answer is "just use a `std::vector`".

Comment: Fair enough I suppose.

Comment: Guys, I don't have any problem with this answer and I'm not the one who downvoted it. I'm just saying that it seems that although this answer is correct, it is probably not what OP is looking for..

Comment: @P0W, ah, I misread it, sorry. LuchianGrigore, I updated your answer a little, so it addresses the input correctly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with allocating an array of 10 ints, if you don't need it to grow dynamically.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the last element in the array then loop through each element reversing the order then storing that to revstr[13]. More on it here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/14951/

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[13], revstr[13];
cin>>str;
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    revstr[13-i-1] = str[i];
}
cout<<revstr<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char str[13];
    char revstr[13];

    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::cin.getline(str, 13);

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        revstr[12 - i] = str[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        std::cout << revstr[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```