# Using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic-allocation

So I've been told to create an array that will accept 10 integers from the user, store it into an array, and sort these values using a pointer bubble sort in ascending order.

I believe I have successfully done this much, but I am having trouble with the second part.

"Dynamically Allocate another array of 10 integers.  Copy elements from the first into the second, but in reverse order (i.e. descending order). Display the elements of the first and second array in order and deallocate the dynamically allocated array."

I am able to display the first array in order, and I know that to deallocate the array you must use the the delete function, but I am not so sure on how to construct the Dynamic Array.

*I have not included the functions since I don't believe they are necessary for this part, but if I do, then I'll post them as well.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and clarifications.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sortArray(int * , int);
void showArray(const int * , int);
int binarySearch(const int *, int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int const MAX_NUM = 10;
    int numbers [MAX_NUM];
    int counter;
    int findval;
    int index;
    char again;

    cout<< "Please enter 10 integer values."<< endl;
    for(counter=0; counter< MAX_NUM ; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value for "<< counter+1 << ": ";
        cin >> *(numbers+counter);
    }


    sortArray(numbers, 10);

    cout << endl << "The values in ascending order are: " << endl;
    showArray(numbers, 10);

    do
    {
        cout<< endl <<  "Enter the value you are searching for: ";
        cin >> findval; 
        cout << endl;
        index = binarySearch(numbers , MAX_NUM , findval);
        // Display the results of the search.
        if (index == -1)
            cout << "Number was not found." << endl << endl;
        else
            cout << "Number "<< findval<<" found in position " << index + 1 << endl << endl;
        // Does the user want to do this again?
        do
        {
            cout << "Would you like to look up another number? (y/n) ";
            cin >> again;
        }
        while(again != 'y' && again != 'Y' && again != 'n' && again != 'N');
    } 
    while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

    cout<< endl << "Thank You. Press the return key to continue...";

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You are not dynamically allocating anything here! Your array is pretty much **statically** allocated `int numbers [MAX_NUM];`

Comment: I know I am not, I'm unsure on how to construct this dynamic array with what I've already put together.

Comment: Raw arrays in C++ are not *dynamic arrays* (grow larger or smaller as needed), but may be allocated dynamically (essentially the `dynamic-arrays` tag is incorrect to use for this question - check the description of the tags when entering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator `new` should be used to allocate memory. For dealloaction use `delete`.

Start from allocation the memory:

```cpp
    int * dynArr = NULL; // pointer to work with dynamic array
    dynArr = new int[MAX_NUM]; // allocation of memory
```

Then check that memory was allocated, like:

```cpp
    if( dynArr != NULL )
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // report about problem and do not use pointer
    }
```

And use function for copying elements, e.g.:

```cpp
void reversCopy(const int * source, int * destination, int number)
// Function for copying numbers from one array (memory) to other 
// in the revers order (first element goes to the last position).
// source - pointer to array where numbers will be read
// destination - pointer to array where numbers will be written
// number - number of elements to be copyed
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[number - 1 - i];
    }
}
```

Eventually, free dymanic memory with operator:

```
  delete[] dynArr;
  dynArr = NULL;
```

and do not use `dynArr` after that.

Comment: For an array in C++, this is not quite the correct answer.

Comment: More specifically, for arrays, `new[]` should be used to allocate memory and `delete[]` to deallocate memory.

Comment: In C++, `std::vector` should be used over `new[]`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sure, but the problem explicitly asks to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Derek `std::vector` is the standard dynamic array in C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The question is not about dynamic arrays.

Comment: `vector` is a vector (template with behaviour similar to array), but it is not an array

Comment: @BaummitAugen i guess for a newbie `vector` would be bit tough to handle, let him learn the basics first

Comment: This is what the instructor is likely expecting to mark.

Comment: Btw, this `if( dynArr != NULL )` stuff is nonsense, `new` never returns a null pointer. I downvoted for this, will remove when you cleaned it up.

Comment: What is meant by source, destination, and number?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Perhaps I am being blinded by my vast intellect making me unable to empathize, but teaching dynamically allocated array before std::vector is placing the cart before the horse. std::vector is pretty much fire-and-forget while the manual memory management involved  in array handling is definitely not what I see as the basics.

Comment: @ElSpiffy Source and destination I don't think can be explained much better. Number is the count of items to copy from source to destination.

Comment: @ElSpiffy: commens are added for function

Comment: @user4581301 I was technically supposed to be taught vectors but the professor said it wouldn't be used in the course I'm in since we are not working objects.

Comment: If I were to call this function to be presented to the user, is it correct to use.  revrsCopy (numbers, 10); ?

Comment: @ElSpiffy Well, your professor is an ignorant twat, and doesn't teach C++ really. Do not take that, I'm recommending about telling them so!

Comment: @ElSpiffy teacher recommended or not, spend some time getting to know the standard containers. They will save you insane amounts of coding and debugging time. Give the instructor what they want--you need to pass the course--but don't limit yourself to the material on which the instructor is grading. For virtually every common problem someone has written a class, structure, function, or library to solve it, and you are a sucker to not use it whenever possible. More important, the standard implementations are almost certainly better and that's less crap to worry about while you focus on passing.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Wanted to comment on the same exact issue, then saw your comment. There is actually an `operator new` overload that can return `nullptr`, namely the [`nothrow` placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). But it's not used here, so indeed the test for `nullptr` is meaningless here, as in case of bad allocation `new` will throw a [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic memory management should be done using the C++ standard classes and concepts as available with either [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) or [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Using C++ language correctly doesn't require you to use `new`/`delete` for most of the use cases you actually need to cover.

Comment: Smart pointers or containers are a good way to go, but something tells me that this is more of an academic exercise to demonstrate an understanding of the process of dynamically allocating and deallocating memory.

Comment: @Derek Well, I don't care about _academia_ as long not stated explicitly. We have these mechanisms in place and asking beyond seems to be much useless. I actually hate academia trying to teach such in first place, before getting the available language constructs right

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 10000% agree. That's why lots of students learn C++ the wrong way, then complain how hard and error-prone the language is. The instructor ends up teaching C with classes. It's not 1981 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically allocate array you need to build code like this:

```
int *arr = new int[size];  // you have to remember to free memory when you won't need this array anymore - use delete[] achieve this
```

size variable don't have to be const and compiler don't need to know value of it during compilation. You can ask user to provide size :) Not to reverse your original table just assassin elements in reversed way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = numbers[size - i - 1]; <-- '-1' to not read outside of orginal array (in C++ index starts with 0)
}
```

If you want to revers table without using new one you should visit: [Reverse Contents in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712903/reverse-contents-in-array/55797344#55797344). There are few methods to do this :)