# Reversing an array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this program that makes and populates an array. Then it is sent to a function called reverse, which reverses the order in the array. The compiler keeps giving errors. I'm not quite sure why.

**CODE**

```
void reverse(int* array, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[size-i];
        array[size-i] = temp;
    } // end of for loop

} // end of reverse 


int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    int array[8];

    // get and print size of the array
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    printf("Size is %d\n", size);

    // populate array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    } // end of for loop

    // display array before reversing
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    } // end of for loop

    // new line
    printf("\n");

    // reverse the array
    reverse(&array, size);

    // display the array again after reversing
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);

    } // end of for loop
} // end of main
```

**It keeps giving me this error**

```
main.cc:17:14: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
                int temp = *array[i];
                           ^~~~~~~~~
main.cc:18:3: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
                *array[i] = *array[size-i];
                ^~~~~~~~~
main.cc:18:15: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
                *array[i] = *array[size-i];
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:19:3: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
                *array[size-i] = temp;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I removed the & in front of the array variable when I send it to reverse. Though it gave me what I think is an address location. Below is the output. Why is that? There is no print statement in my code that intentionally prints any address.

Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1412676568 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
[Finished in 0.5s]

Comment: Your reverse function has an off-by-one error.  Think about what happens when i == 0.

Comment: Your code says `int temp = array[i];`, the error says `int temp = *array[i];`.  The posted code is correct.  Please make sure that the code you post produces the error you are asking about in future.

Comment: @ConradoSanchez: That is a different question.  You need to ask separately.  (But it is the off-by-one error that people have told you about twice).

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this problem a little differently, maybe you will use this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void displayArray(int table[], int size);

void rev(int table[], int size);

void fillTheArray(int table[], int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int myArray[8];
    int size = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
    std::cout << "Array size is: " << size << std::endl;

    fillTheArray(myArray, size);
    displayArray(myArray, size);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    rev(myArray, size);
    displayArray(myArray, size);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void fillTheArray(int table[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        table[i] = i;
    }
}

void displayArray(int table[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << table[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void rev(int table[], int size) {

    int *start = table;
    int *end = table + (size - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (start < end) {
            int temp = *end;
            *end = *start;
            *start = temp;
        }

        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two errors in this code. First is: wrong way of passing parametr to function:

```
 // reverse the array
 reverse(&array, size);
```

you should do this just like this(array name is pointer to first element of this array):

```
reverse(array, size);
```

Second problem is with reverser - you try to access some random memory outside arrar range:

```
array[i] = array[size-i];
```

Remember that in C++ array index's start with 0 not 1. So if your array is size of 8 - largest insext of this array is 7 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). Your code should look like this:

```
array[i] = array[size -i -1];
```

And it should work as you expected.

It is my solution with pointers:

```
void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
    int* head = arr;
    int* tail = arr + count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
    {
        if (head < tail)
        {
            int tmp = *tail;
            *tail = *head;
            *head = tmp;

            head++; tail--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

or just use functions build in C++: std::reverse in 'algorithm' library.

It's a lot of examples on stackoverflow with this kind of examples:
[Reverse Contents in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712903/reverse-contents-in-array/55797344#55797344)

Answer (score -1):

You have fixed most of the compiler errors in your code except one.

The line

```
reverse(&array, size);
```

should be

```
reverse(array, size);
```

After that is fixed, you have to fix logic errors in `reverse`.

You are using the wrong index for accessing the upper half of the array.

```
void reverse(int* array, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[size-i];  // When i is 0, you are accessing array[size]
                                   // That is incorrect.
        array[size-i] = temp;
    } // end of for loop

} // end
```

You need to use

```
void reverse(int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[size-i-1];
        array[size-i-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Another way to approach the algorithm would be to use two indices.

```
void reverse(int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0, j = size-1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Working program: http://ideone.com/ReVnGR.

Comment: This is not the OP's problem either.   This should be a comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I noticed that the OP had updated the code to remove all the other errors. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

You're passing **int instead of *int to the reverse method:

```
reverse(&array, size);
```

Pass it like that:

```
reverse(array, size);
```

Comment: This is not the OPs problem.  The problem is that the posted code doesn't have the error he is complaining about.

Comment: @MartinBonner Are you downvoting all these answers ?

Comment: I have downvoted answers which don't answer the question the OP has asked.  (Making additional comments in an answer which *does* answer the OPs question is fine, so is explaining why the OP has asked the wrong question, and answering the question they *should* have asked - but *just* pointing out other problems should only be a comment)